# Will separate crawled properties gets created for same site columns present in two site collections?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Will separate crawled properties gets created for site columns having same name and type in two site collections? If so, is there a way to find out which crawled property represents (site column in) which site collection? Or will it create only one crawled property for both the site columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only create on crawled property, given that the Internal Name and the type of the columns are the same.